# Круглый border в Safari

Tags: css3, css

Подскажите как решить проблему в Сафари с круглым бордером

обрезка углов изображения

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/5axs8/

Comment: у меня все отлично работает

Comment: какая версия Сафари?

Comment: Версия 6.1.1 (7537.73.11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/4b8p3/ - работает когда задаешь изображение через background

Answer (score 0):

добавь background-size: cover;

Comment: у меня 5.1.7 - не работает

Comment: ты добавил background-size: cover; ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mE7Lj/ - не работает